# Using Date Range in Google Search API with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-search, google-search-api

I am using the `google-search` gem for `Ruby` found [here](https://github.com/tj/google-search).

And I'm trying to make my search within a custom date range.

```
results = Google::Search::Web.new(query: "SearchTerm daterange:2455197-2455562")
```

That doesn't seem to work and just ignores the `daterange` which is how you would do the search normally with `Google`. So it gives me the results for the term with no date range.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Or maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: I have no experience with 'google-search' gem, following
>   solutions are **NOT tested**!

According to [google docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search?hl=en#restrict_to_range), the api expects something like:

```
https://www.google.com/cse?cx=12345:example&q=lebanese+restaurant&sort=review-date:r:20090301:20090430
```

To make **google-search** populate this request for us, you could try two things:

1. Use [`order_by` option](https://github.com/tj/google-search/blob/master/lib/google-search/search/mixins/order_by.rb) (which is not documented but i imagine it will do sorting)

   results = Google::Search::Web.new(query: "SearchTerm", order: "review_date:r:2455197-2455562")

2.According to gem ReadMe:

> #### Arbitrary Query String Support
>
> Arbitrary key / value pairs may be passed to Google::Search.new, all
>   options passed that are not assigned (deleted) will pass on to be part
>   of the query string.

So, theoretically we could do:

```
results = Google::Search::Web.new(query: "SearchTerm", sort: "review_date:r:2455197-2455562")
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up abandoning that gem and using a combination of PhantomJS and Nokogiri to get the job done.